# How to get the progress of download in python headless chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to get the status or percentage of download in headless chrome in python. I have tried below code but in headless mode it is throwing error `shadowRoot is null`

```
from selenium import webdriver
def get_download_progress():
    progress = driver.execute_script('''
    
    var tag = document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot;
    var intag = tag.querySelector('downloads-item').shadowRoot;
    var progress_tag = intag.getElementById('progress');
    var progress = null;
    if(progress_tag) {
        progress = progress_tag.value;
    }
    return progress;
    
    ''')
    return progress

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# do some staff

driver.get('chrome://downloads/')

progress = get_download_progress()

print("Progress: ", progress)
```